# Which magnetic force is stronger? Electron or proton?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons, protons

Assume the particles generates the magnetic field with their own spin. No motions except spin.(they have their intrinsic angular momentum.) Then which one generates stronger magnetic force?

I've seen the formula which represents the magnetic moment of the 1/2 spin particles with charge $q$, mass $m$, $\vec{\mu}=\frac{g_sq}{2m}\vec{S}$ where $g_s$ called [g-factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-factor_%28physics%29).

But I can't understand the formula.

Let me ask a question, which magnetic force is stronger between electron and proton?

Answer (score 1):

Thats the magnetic moment as you said, not the magnetic force, if you ask wich one has a bigger magnetic moment, the proton has the bigger g-factor, around 5.6, while the electron is 2.

Now, that means that under a magnetic field you may get force and even a torque (Depending on the magnetic field) on the particle, how strong it is depends on the magnetic moment.